# Keep WebSocket connection open without receiving incoming frames

Tags: kotlin, websocket, kotlin-coroutines, ktor

I'm building a real-time game (in Kotlin using the Ktor framework) where users connect to the WebSocket first, and the server only starts attempting to receive incoming frames after the game round starts.

In a chat-like application, the server could start receiving incoming frames immediately after opening the connection, but I want to be able to call `receiveDeserialized<T>()` with different types `T` that cannot be known before the game starts.

I've tried doing something like the following:

```kotlin
lateinit var connection: DefaultWebSocketServerSession
// ...
routing {
  webSocket("mySocket") {
    connection = this
  }
}
```

... and later when the game has started:

```kotlin
connection.receiveDeserialized<MyData>()
```

This, however, causes the WebSocket connection to be closed by the server (according to some googling, this is because the lambda for `webSocket` terminates).

Inside `webSocket { ... }` I can do `for (frame in incoming) { println(frame) }` to keep the connection open, however that way incoming frames are *intercepted* and I can't receive them elsewhere.

What can I do to accomplish what I'm trying to do? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can try the other way around by calling a service from the handler to determine what types to deserialize to.